# Using custom classes in tailwind, how to specify one class for a small breakpoint, and another for a large?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I've got an external stylesheet that I am importing classes from in my react project:

```
import { leftBlock, rightBlock, topBlock, bottomBlock } from 'layout.module.css'
```

And in the HTML portion:

```
<div className={leftBlock}>
```

I want to take advantage of tailwind's breakpoints, and use `bottomBlock` at the `sm` breakpoint, but I don't know how to combine this. I don't even know what to Google. I've tried:

```
<div className={leftBlock 'sm:${bottomBlock}'}
```

But the compiler hates it. What do I need to do? Am I just thinking about this wrong?

Comment: are the classes you are importing tailwind classes?

Comment: The classes I'm importing are custom classes.

Comment: It turned out I needed to stop the recompiling process and start again, not sure what happened, but then react wouldn't compile any tailwind responsive prefixes in class names so I gave up on trying to use tailwind classes and wrote standard media queries instead.

Answer (score -1):

In Tailwind CSS, you can create customized CSS classes for specific breakpoints using the `@screen` directive to define custom responsive breakpoints.

Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@screen sm {
  .leftBlock {
    /* Your customized styles for small breakpoint */
  }
}

@screen lg {
  .rightBlock {
    /* Your customized styles for large breakpoint */
  }
}
```

In this example:

- The @screen directive is used to define the custom responsive breakpoints.
- Within the @screen directive for sm (small) and lg (large), you can define your customized CSS classes (e.g., .custom-small and .custom-large) with the specific styles you want to apply at those breakpoints.

After defining these custom classes, you can use them in your HTML templates just like any other Tailwind CSS classes. For example:

```
<div class="leftBlock lg:rightBlock">
  <!-- Content -->
</div>
```

This will apply the custom-small class at the small breakpoint and the custom-large class at the large breakpoint.

Comment: The issue that I am having is adding a class at a breakpoint into the react `className` property. I don't know what the syntax should be or if it's possible.

Comment: I think we cannot use classes like your way. to use your classes at a breakpoint, you can re-define css codes into `@screen`.

Comment: I'm not sure how you mean. Can you please give an example or a link to documentation?

Comment: I will edit my answer. please try it.

Comment: I'm not sure React will be able to import that if the class is nested but I will see what I can do with it.

Comment: Yeah, nesting the class is invalid.